# Finding the wavelength of maximum absorption and Crystal Field Splitting of [Ni(H2O)6]2+

Tags: physical-chemistry, crystal-field-theory, ligand-field-theory

*(I haven't been here for a long time, so tell me if my formatting is fine)*

**Given**

> The $\ce{[Ni(H2O)6]^2+}$ complex appears green in solution from the transmitted light. Estimate the wavelength of maximum absorption, and also the crystal field splitting $Δ_0$.

**I got 1.59ev for the CFS, but I want to verify if I'm doing this right.**

I wasn't sure if I also need to know the wavelengths of light and spin pairing energy for this problem. So I just looked up the average wavelength of red light (650nm) and plugged it in (and ignored spin pairing energy since my prof never talked about it)

**My Method**

Since H20 isn't charged, so Ni is 2+ to make this complex 2+.
Since $\ce{Ni^2+}$ is $[Ar]3d^8$, and water makes a weak ligand field, I basically did Crystal Field method and filled the bottom row (t2g) with 6 electrons and put the remaining 2 electrons in eg.

I then used stablization energy: $ΔE = -6(2/5)Δ_0+2(3/5)Δ_0=-6/5Δ_0$

And then $ΔE = hv = hc/λ= 6/5Δ_0$ (I think I can exclude that negative sign since I'm just finding the splitting)

to get $Δ_0 = 5hc/(6(650nm)) = 1.59ev $

Comment: Absorption of a photon (loosely speaking) causes the transition $\mathrm{t_{2g} \to \mathrm{e_g}}$. The energy needed for this is (by definition) exactly $\Delta_O$, which doesn't actually have anything to do with the CFSE or the electron configuration, so you've gone one step too far.